# Django REST Framework | Ordering by Count from a ManyToMany Field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

I'm following a Django REST Framework's Course, but I got stuck trying to set the **ordering** configuration from **django_filters** into a **ViewSet**.

```
ordering = ('-members__count')
```

In the original code of the Course, `-members__count` is used as query to return total members count, but when I try to use the same syntax I got this error:

**Error:**

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'count' into field. Choices are: auth_token, circle, created, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, invitation, invited_by, is_active, is_client, is_staff, is_superuser, is_verified, issued_by, last_login, last_name, logentry, membership, modified, password, phone_number, profile, user_permissions, username
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding this error, but all these suggested options correspond to Fields from my model. Also, in the Course its indicated that is a query representation format to get the total count of that field, so I'm a little confuse about that.

Anyway, this is a resume of my code but you also can see my full detailed code in this repo in case to be required: https://github.com/cadasmeq/comparte_ride/tree/master/cride/circles.

**View:**

```
# Filters
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter, OrderingFilter
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class CircleViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """Circle view set."""

    serializer_class = CircleModelSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug_name'

    # Filters
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    search_fields = ('slug_name', 'name')
    ordering_fields = ('rides_offered', 'rides_taken', 'name', 'created', 'member_limit')
    ordering = ('-members__count', '-rides_offered', '-rides_taken')
    filter_fields = ('verified', 'is_limited')
```

**Model:**

```
class Circle(CRideModel):
"""Circle model.

A circle is a private group where rides are offered and taken
by its members. To join a circle a user must receive an unique
invitation code from an existing circle member.
"""

members = models.ManyToManyField(
    "users.User",
    through='circles.Membership',
    through_fields=('circle', 'user')
)
```

Thanks a lot guys beforehand, and Im sorry about rusty English haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because you are trying to access a property of the `User` model. It doesn't find `count` on the `User` model.
What I understand you are trying to do is order by the number of members of each circle on the `ManyToManyField` `members`.

To do that i would use `annotate`, rename `members__count` to `members_count` and do something like (untested):

```py
from django.db.models import Count

class CircleViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """Circle view set."""

    serializer_class = CircleModelSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug_name'

    # Filters
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    search_fields = ('slug_name', 'name')
    ordering_fields = ('rides_offered', 'rides_taken', 'name', 'created', 'member_limit')
    ordering = ('-members_count', '-rides_offered', '-rides_taken')
    filter_fields = ('verified', 'is_limited')

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Restrict list to public-only."""
        queryset = Circle.objects.annotate(members_count=Count('members')).all()
        if self.action == 'list':
            return queryset.filter(is_public=True)
        return queryset
```